# MySQL Selecting Average Sales data of a product over time

Tags: mysql, select, time

I have the following MySQL table as per the image below. The Table is named example_table:
[image: example_table definition]

The Table contains a list of products that have been sold, the time that they were sold as well as the selling price.

Now I was attempting to do some 'analytics' on the table to determine average selling price for sales in the **5 preceding days** given a particular inputted date entered by the user.

***The output I am trying to achieve is as follows.***
[image: Expected Result of 5 day sale query]

I have part of the query but It's not exactly what I require .

```
SELECT product_name,time_value,AVG(selling_price) as 'Average Selling Price'
from example_table
where product_name='Samsung Galaxy S4'
and time_value in (
(SELECT SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 1 DAY)),
(SELECT SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 2 DAY)),
(SELECT SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 3 DAY)),
(SELECT SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 4 DAY)),
(SELECT SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 5 DAY)))
group by product_name,time_value
order by time_value asc
```

This query gives the following result however Note the missing days.

[image: SQL Result of attempted query]

I.E No Sales data is present on May 16 and May 17 and I need this shown in the result as per the expected results image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT
  d.date,
  d.product_name,
  COALESCE(AVG(selling_price), 0) as 'Average Selling Price'
from
(
   SELECT 'Samsung Galaxy S4' AS Product_name, 
          SUBDATE('2013-05-21', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS date
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Samsung Galaxy S4', SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 2 DAY)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Samsung Galaxy S4', SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 3 DAY)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Samsung Galaxy S4', SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 4 DAY)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Samsung Galaxy S4', SUBDATE('2013-05-21',INTERVAL 5 DAY)
) AS d 
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT *
   FROM example_table
   WHERE product_name = 'Samsung Galaxy S4' 
) AS e ON d.date = e.time_value
group by d.product_name, d.date
order by d.date asc;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0107/5)

This will give you:

```
|       DATE |      PRODUCT_NAME | AVERAGE SELLING PRICE |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-05-16 | Samsung Galaxy S4 |                     0 |
| 2013-05-17 | Samsung Galaxy S4 |                     0 |
| 2013-05-18 | Samsung Galaxy S4 |                 517.5 |
| 2013-05-19 | Samsung Galaxy S4 |                 482.5 |
| 2013-05-20 | Samsung Galaxy S4 |                   460 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [SQLFIddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0107/7).

```
SELECT 
 @rn := @rn - 1 AS row_num,@am := DATE_SUB('2013-05-21', INTERVAL @rn DAY ) AS 'time_value',et.product_name,
 IFNULL((SELECT 
    AVG(er.selling_price)
  FROM 
   example_table er
    WHERE 
   er.time_value = @am
  GROUP BY @am ),0) AS 'Average Selling Price' 
FROM 
 (SELECT @rn := 6 , @am := DATE_SUB('2013-05-21', INTERVAL @rn DAY) ) r ,
 example_table et 
 WHERE et.product_name = "Samsung Galaxy S4" AND et.time_value > DATE_SUB('2013-05-21', INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

Comment: Thankyou. A Nice neat solution that works perfectly using user defined variables!